# SQL group three columns into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with three columns:

```
[ID]  [name]         [link]
1     sample_name_1  sample_link_1
2     sample_name_2  sample_link_2
3     sample_name_3  sample_link_3
```

I need to somehow group them into one column, so the ideal result is this:

```
[one_column]
1
sample_name_1
sample_name_1
2
sample_name_2
sample_link_2
3
sample_name_3
sample_link_3
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to look and how to get it done in SQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to use `VALUES` table value constructor with `CROSS APPLY`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   ID int,
   name varchar(50),
   link varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, name, link)
VALUES
   (1, 'sample_name_1', 'sample_link_1'),
   (2, 'sample_name_2', 'sample_link_2'),
   (3, 'sample_name_3', 'sample_link_3')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT v.one_column
FROM MyTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
  (1, CONVERT(varchar(50), ID)), 
  (2, CONVERT(varchar(50), name)), 
  (3, CONVERT(varchar(50), link))
) v (rn, one_column)
ORDER BY t.ID, v.rn
```

Result:

```
one_column
1
sample_name_1
sample_link_1
2
sample_name_2
sample_link_2
3
sample_name_3
sample_link_3
```

Comment: This is a neat solution.

Comment: Nice solution, well explained. deserves +1

Answer (score 2):

While this is something you should do in your presentation layer (i.e. your app or Website) you *can* do this in SQL:

```
select one column
from
(
  select cast(id as varchar(10)) as one column, id as sortkey1, 1 as sortkey2 from mytable
  union all
  select name as one column, id as sortkey1, 2 as sortkey2 from mytable
  union all
  select link as one column, id as sortkey1, 3 as sortkey2 from mytable
) unioned
order by sortkey1, sortkey2;
```